# What happen behind the scene when using between "@include(or import)" and ": (inheritance")?

Tags: objective-c

the more i study and research, the less i understand now.. very frustrating.. 
But, still try to figure it out i hope anyone who knows in detail, please help me out :)

What i know is when i use "@import(include) (file1)", it does nothing but putting file1 in current source file so that i can.... use the name of file...(I'm not so sure..)
And,

The Question is then when i inherit file1.h, every definition included in file1.m can be inherited..?
What about the "include" case..? it also include file1.m behind the scene..? or my program just knows declaration in file1.h and can refer to real definition at runtime..?

Sorry if my question is a bit not organised cuz even my brain is not organised as well Y.Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Question is then when i inherit file1.h, every definition included
>   in file1.m can be inherited..?

You don't inherit a file, you #include or #import it. Actually the thing is easier than you think.

In any source code file, you use functions and objects. For example you can use `NSString` or a custom object `MyClass`. But the compiler and the linker needs to know WHERE is the definition of those objects and functions, so that it can verify the syntax and link with the appropriate libraries.

Say you use MyClass in some source file.

```
MyClass myclass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

The compiler doesn't know what `MyClass` is, so you write this

```
#include "MyClass.h"
```

This tells the compiler that it should look into that header file when looking up objects. So what about `MyClass.m`? Well, at the point where you're object is being compiled the contents of MyClass.m don't matter, because that will be resolved later, by the linker.

Comment: you can also `@import` it... which is what the question is about, does an `@import` `@import` its `@imports`?

Answer (score 0):

In objectiveC you will use "import"
In C you will use "include"

In Xcode you can right in c and ObjectiveC.

Basically what is dose, is take the file that you imported and place is before the file that you imported it from, before the program compiles.

For Example if i use "import myViewController.h", in the class "mainViewController.m"
The class that i imported it to("mainViewController.m"), can use all the properties that are at the "@interface" at the "import myViewController.h" file.

Hope my answer is clear enough..

Comment: `@import` is a new construct and distinct from `#import` it has linker implications as well.

Answer (score 0):

The implications to the visibility of symbols should be exactly the same.

If you are dealing with `somelib.h`, and in my module.c you `@import somelib;`
it should give you the same symbols in that compilation unit as if you did `#import <somelib.h>`
but you wouldn't have to add the framework in your linking phase.